# Issue with npm Install behind a corporate proxy

Tags: node.js, git, proxy, npm

I am following the below steps:

**Step1:** I tried to clone the AngularJS Tutorial repository using the below command

```
git clone https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat.git
```

The repo got successfully clonned in my C:\Git

Since I am working behind a corporate proxy and I checked from various forums that i have to set the http_proxy and https_proxy, So i performed Step2.

**Step2:** Create Environment Variables http_proxy and https_proxy

```
http_proxy = http://userid:PASSWORD%24%25@domain:port 
https_proxy = https://userid:PASSWORD%24%25@domain:port
```

Set npm config

```
npm config set proxy http://userid:PASSWORD%24%25@domain:port 
npm config set http_proxy http://userid:PASSWORD%24%25@domain:port 
npm config set https_proxy http://userid:PASSWORD%24%25@domain:port
```

(%24 for $ symbol and %25 for % symbol)

**Step3:** Now I opened node.js Command Prompt.
and I changed the directroy to C:\Git\angular-phonecat and typed in the below command.

```
C:\Git\angular-phonecat>npm install
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@0.3.5
|


> ws@0.4.32 install C:\Git\angular-phonecat\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


C:\Git\angular-phonecat\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash._objecttypes/-/lodash._objecttypes-2.4.1.tgz
|
> angular-phonecat@0.0.0 postinstall C:\Git\angular-phonecat
> bower install

bower bootstrap#~3.1.1    ECONNREFUSED Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/bootstrap failed: connect ECONNREFUSED

npm ERR! angular-phonecat@0.0.0 postinstall: `bower install`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-phonecat@0.0.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the angular-phonecat package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     bower install
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-phonecat
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Git\angular-phonecat
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Git\angular-phonecat\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Any work around would be much appreciated.

Comment: you need to call bower install first if  node is not doing it implicitly in its package.json.

Comment: I called the bower install, i am getting this error bower jquery#~2.1.1       ECONNREFUSED Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/jquery failed: connect ECONNREFUSED

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install an in-the-middle digesting proxy (such as cntlm, see http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/) depending on your proxy needs.

You can find what proxy your graphical browsers are using with this command: (see https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7156)

`reg query "HKCU\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\internet Settings" /v "ProxyServer"`